# NSA and facebook chats

Tags: tls

Can you guess how the NSA can read Facebook chats, while Facebook does use SSL encryption?
Requesting information directly from the Facebook HQ is possible (see also who betrayed Facebook in favor of the NSA), but if you read the details of this program you will see that they are talking about the raw TCP packages.

"enables an analyst using XKeyscore to read the content of Facebook chats " http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jul/31/nsa-top-secret-program-online-data

PS:

Former Facebook security chief is now working for the NSA

Read more: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2347047/Former-Facebook-security-chief-working-NSA.html#ixzz2aekPnnJS

Answer (score 4):

SSL only protects communication between your system and Facebook's system.  Since Facebook is a willing participant, they simply provide access to their database which stores the conversations in the clear.

Comment: Yes, but If you read the details of this X-Keyscore program, you will see that it talks about raw TCP/IP packages.

Comment: @user129789 - no where in the linked article did it say anything I could find about TCP/IP.  In theory, depending on the type of SSL, if the private certificate was shared, then the SSL key exchange could be decoded and HTTPS traffic could be directly decoded, but this would still be due to collusion on Facebook's part.  Facebook is in the business of selling your information, this really shouldn't be a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

This seems simple enough: SSL is just between your computer and the Facebook servers. The Facebook servers, by construction, see all the data unencrypted. If I were the NSA, I would simply request from Facebook themselves a copy of the whole lot.

Comment: Yes, but If you read the details of this X-Keyscore program, you will see that it talks about raw TCP/IP packages.